# Induction to remove current from superconductor?

Tags: superconductivity

I’ve read how you can insert current into a superconductor. I was wondering if you could use a similar method of induction to remove current from the superconductor for use.

Comment: what do you mean in "how you can insert current into a superconductor"? 
Is it by an applied magnetic field? If yes, when the answer is YES, you can "remove" current from SC by magnetic filed.

Comment: Yeah that’s what I meant.